# Put PDF into NSData

Tags: iphone

How do I put my PDF into `NSData`?  I have the location of the PDF as a string in my Documents Directory of the app.  When I try to email it, I see the PDF in the body of the email (vs seeing an attachment icon.  I don't know if that's normal or not).  But when I receive the email on the other end, it does not have a PDF extension.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [self GetURLForPDF]; // I know this name is bad since it is really a NSString
NSLog(@"DocumentsDirectory: %@", documentsDirectory);
NSString *pdfName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.pdf", documentsDirectory, title];
NSLog(@"pdfName: %@", pdfName);
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfName];
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:title];    
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on how the pdfName variable is being set, it looks like your "title" value does not include the PDF suffix. Have you tried:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [self GetURLForPDF]; // I know this name is bad since it is really a NSString
NSLog(@"DocumentsDirectory: %@", documentsDirectory);
NSString *fullTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", title];
NSString *pdfName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fullTitle];
NSLog(@"pdfName: %@", pdfName);
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfName];
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fullTitle];    
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```