# Converting a pdf image to NSData for Parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, nsdata

I am using vector graphics in my application and want to store some on Parse.com. I need to first convert these to NSData before upload. Is it possible to convert a pdf file to NSData?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coolImage.pdf"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);
```

I know NSData allows for a jpg of png representation but what about pdfs? Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how about you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535635/put-pdf-into-nsdata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//to convert pdf to NSData
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"]; 
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
```