# Converting a PDF image to NSData for Parse.com in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am creating PDFs in my application and want to upload them to Parse.com. I need to first convert the PDF images to `NSData` before uploading. I know it is possible in Objective-C:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
```

However, is it possible to convert a PDF file to `NSData` in Swift? The following does not work:

```
var pdfPath: String = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
var myData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(pdfPath)
```

Relevant links:

[Converting a pdf image to NSData for Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849795/converting-a-pdf-image-to-nsdata-for-parse-com)

[Put PDF into NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535635/put-pdf-into-nsdata)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code for `myData`:

```
var pdfPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
var PDFUrl = NSURL(string: pdfPath)            //convert pdfPath string to NSURL
var myData = NSData(contentsOfURL: PDFUrl!)
```